# Chrome, SVGs and max-height

Tags: google-chrome, svg, responsive-design, css

I am having problems with chrome and svgs.

I would like 2 svgs to be 100% of the screen width up to 400px. So when on mobile screens they align vertically and then on desktop they align horizontally.

This is happening in all the browsers I've checked except for chrome. I'll explain more below.

relevant SVG

```
   viewport 0 0 400 150
```

relevant CSS

```
.svg{
margin-right:auto;
margin-left:auto;
width: 100%;
max-width: 400px;
background-color: aliceblue;
max-height: 150px;
}
```

relevant javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script  type="text/javascript">
var imageWidth = 1*$(window).width();
var imageHeight = .425*$(window).width();
$("document").ready(function(){
        $(".svg").css("width", imageWidth);
        $(".svg").css("height",imageHeight);
});   
</script>
```

relevant HTML

```
    <object class="svg" type="image/svg+xml"  data="/svg/betterLearning1.svg" >
    </object>    
    <object class="svg" type="image/svg+xml"  data="/svg/betterLearning2.svg" >
    </object>
```

When I look at inspect element in Chrome I can see that the css max-width has over-written the javascript generated width but it has not chamged the height and that remains as per the script.

EDIT
A potential workaround is to limit the javascript variables before they generate the css..

```
if (imageWidth > 400){
    imageWidth = 400;
 }
if (imageHeight > 150){
imageHeight = 150;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Responsive INLINE SVG - content of svg must fill parent width](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16813829/responsive-inline-svg-content-of-svg-must-fill-parent-width)