# Responsive INLINE SVG - content of svg must fill parent width

Tags: html, svg, responsive-design

**GOAL:**

I am trying to get an `INLINE SVG` element to fill the full available width of the parent element. I can achieve the same effect easily using an `img` and `object` tag to reference the svg file, but I want to use `inline svg` because I am animating the svg inner elements with javascript.

**PROBLEM:**

I can achieve this in Firefox and with some tweaks also in Chrome, but safari and IE9 & IE10 won't play ball.

- The inner content of svg doesn't always fill the svg element in all screen widths
- webkit adds a mysterious padding/height (in this example the padding is within svg element) The height of SVG element should be auto and wrap the inner svg content.

**MAIN QUESTION:**

**Is there a cross browser solution for responsive INLINE SVG:** View the example in IE9 & 10 and -webkit-Safari and notice the unrequired extra height within SVG element (cyan color).

http://jsfiddle.net/David_Knowles/9tUAd/

```
<div class="block">stuff</div> 
<div class="wrap">
    <svg version="1.1" baseProfile="basic" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 550 350" xml:space="preserve" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">

        <rect x="0" y="0" width="550" height="350"/>
        <polyline points="0,0 0,350 550,350"/>
        <text x="0" y="50%" fill="#ffffff" stroke="none" width="100%">The text</text>
    </svg>
</div>
<div class="block">stuff</div>
```

Comment: Try adapting even the viewbox. In a project of mine I had similar problem and I solved adapting the size of the image and its viewbox with JS

Answer (score 25):

The first problem is that you are setting your `.svg-wrap` div to 100% height. 100% of what? In this case, that div's parent element is the body element. When you've got block-level content that's 100% of the body's height, and other in-flow elements, you're always going to have a vertical scrollbar. because you will always have contents of 100% + your `.stuff` elements. Just as a general tip, constant overflow like this should be the tipoff that something is wonky in your css.

Continuing further into the DOM, the 100% height declaration on your `svg` element is forcing the `svg` to expand to the overly tall wrapper. And that's another part of the culprit.

The solution I use involves [intrinsic ratios](http://alistapart.com/article/creating-intrinsic-ratios-for-video). CSS like this:

```
.svg-wrap {
    background-color:red;
    height:0;
    padding-top:63.63%; /* 350px/550px */
    position: relative;
}

svg {
    background-color: cyan;
    height: 100%;
    display:block;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pcEjd/

Tested in latest, FF, Chrome, Safari, (though not IE).

The downsides of this approach are that:

a) you have to precalculate ratios for all your boxes, or write a script that does so. Not too bad.

b) you can't use `border-box` globally with the star selector, or if you do you need to override box-sizing back to `content-box` for your svg containers. Do-able.

As a side note, this obviously isn't how things are supposed to work. Browsers should be smart enough to look at the SVG viewBox attribute to get the proportions, calculate the computedwidth (after any maxWidth limits) and then compute the height.

But it doesn't currently work that way. There's another weird bug in Chrome where adding `max-width:100%` to the svg creates a situation where the svg always sizes to the smallest rendered size. Try loading this fiddle in Chrome:

http://jsfiddle.net/ynmey/1/

An you'll see no SVG at all! Weird. Even weirder, toggle off the `max-width` declaration in Dev Tools, and then start playing with the width of the "result" viewport in jsfiddle. Take it slightly narrower, then wider, then narrower, then wider. Notice that once the svg gets nudged smaller, it doesn't resize back up again when the viewport gets bigger!

This is important to note because:

```
 * {max-width:100%}
```

is a common (and totally legit) responsive design approach, and it currently wreaks havoc with SVG in Blink. So stick to intrinsic ratios for now.

Comment: Thanks Ben. I used the JS solution as it was something I has already started. Your confirmation of the symptoms is very helpful, and the additional research very valuable. This works!

Comment: Spent ages on this and just adding the css and svg definitions worked magic for me!

Answer (score 10):

The default display type for **inline** SVG elements is `display: inline;`. This means that the SVG element is placed on the typographic baseline of its parent and is aligned accordingly. There is always some space below the baseline to allow for the dangling bits of characters like g and j and such.

Easy fix: `svg { display: block;}` or `svg { display: inline-block; vertical-align: top; }`.

Comment: Thx! Great tip. But unfortunately it doesn't solve the issue. I have added your suggestion to the fiddle demo and as you can see the issue remains in chrome, safari, and IE

Comment: it's this valid for new browser versions?

Comment: As far as I can tell, no. I've tried that display: block said here and it' doesn't work in Chrome version 101

Comment: What worked for me is <svg.... width="100%" height="100%"> at least in chrome it performs correctly and fills the container. However, the path elements inside the svg doesn't scale, obviously

Answer (score 3):

I'm not entirely sure what effect you're trying to achieve, but I think you might be looking for preserveAspectRatio ="xMinYMin slice"

Comment: My apologies for any ambiguity with the phrasing of the question. I want inline SVG to behave exactly the same as an image would in a responsive context; i.e. scale the SVG width — and in this case, it's inner contents — to fill the available parent width proportionally. What happens is that the SVG outer element scales but the inner elements do not scale consistently across all browsers. The example illustrates the differences. Take a look in the various browsers and you'll see the broad range results. Using slice just masks the svg contents without proportional scaling.

Answer (score 3):

I've managed to achieve consistent results in Webkit/Gecko browsers by setting a `height` value other than `auto` or `0`.  In my example I use `1%`, but from what I can tell it could be anything.  Somehow this resolves the incorrect height in Webkit (from my tests I think `auto` incorrectly sets the SVG height to `100%` window height).

I haven't tested this in IE yet.  Please let me know if it works.

http://jsfiddle.net/yXeru/

Comment: Sounds interesting. Let us know what the results are of your browser tests.

Comment: I can confirm that setting the SVG height to 1% using CSS fixes the issue

Answer (score 1):

After much fiddling, the modern browser *and* IE11 compatible solution I used has two parts:

1. Specify both `viewBox` and `preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet"` in the svg root tag.
2. Use css media queries to give your svg element a height in `vw` units for each layout.

good luck!